# Magento 2.4.6: how to setup cron for group:index to run less frequently than every minute?

Tags: magento2, cron, deadlock

Cron tasks in Magento are executed every minute and when product import and indexing tasks are executed simultaneously database deadlock occurs. Changing settings in "System > Cron (Scheduled Tasks)  > Cron configuration options for group:index" doesn't help, all indexing tasks still run every minute.

How can I make it to run every e.g. 30 minutes at least? I don't want to change frequency of main cron (bin/magento cron:run) so that other tasks wouldn't be affected.